# How do C++ functor constructors get called when used with for_each or std::transform

Tags: c++, functor

I've never used c++ functors before and so I'm just trying to understand how they work.

e.g. suppose we have this functor class

```
class MultiplyBy {
private:
    int factor;

public:
    MultiplyBy(int x) : factor(x) { }

    int operator () (int other) const {
        return factor * other;
    }
};
```

Using it like this is clear to me:

```
MultiplyBy mult_3(3);

int x = mult_3(100);
```

Obviosuly the constructor of MultiplyBy is being called with the argument 3.

But in the following case, how is the constructor being called with the value in the array?

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::transform(array, array + 5, array, MultiplyBy(3));
```

Comment: there is no for_each declaration... isn't the title incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of transform being structured like this:

```
void transform(Iterator b, Iterator e, Functor f)
{
    for(;b != e; ++b)
    {
        *b = f(*b);
    }
}
```

The functor is passed by value into the function.
So when you call like this:

```
std::transform(array, array + 5, array, MultiplyBy(3));
```

Here you have created a temporary object. This is passed as a parameter value into transfer(). This results in the functor being copied into the function (not a problem since it has only a POD member and the compiler generated copy constructor works just fine). The parameter can then be used normally.

Note: The temporary object is destroyed at the end of the expression that it was created in (which will be after transform() returns).

Comment: I believe transform, and most(all?) other algorithms in the standard library take their functors by value.  It's irrelevant in this case as it is in most cases.  But it could be an issue in some cases and I think the point should be made clear.

Comment: +1 to that Lindley. Functors are passed as type, and not as argument.

Comment: This _is_ an issue. Functors are passed by value for backward compatibility with C, where pointers are generally passed by value. Also, if the functor would be passed as const then the function-call operator would have to be const. That is often a show-stopper for functors.

Comment: "since it has no members" - um, are you sure?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: If I wasn't a nit picker myself :-)

Answer (score 4):

Well, in the final case, you are creating a new `MultiplyBy` object with 3 as the constructor argument. This object is then passed into `std::transform`, that it then calls `operator()` on.

If it helps you understand better, this is identical:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
MultiplyBy times3(3);
std::transform(array, array + 5, array, times3);
```

Comment: oh yes, that makes sense now.  Especially when I look at the transform template code.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

Answer (score 2):

`MultiplyBy(3)` creates an *unnamed* temporary variable that's pass into `transform` and (at that point) given the corresponding name of the parameter in that function.